# How to validate cookie after logout when user call it from postman not from browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, postman

Basic MVC Form Authentication has been implemented, On Logout i have clear & abandon session, and also send cookies (after Setting expiration date) in response.
the problem is if user have previous cookie, he can keep using application without any interruption from postman.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();

HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie1.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-1);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
```

I want prevent user from using application from all means.
he should not be able to use application with old cookie, should be promt to log in.

Answer (score 0):

[Limitations of Forms Authentication at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_Security_FormsAuthentication_SignOut)

Calling the SignOut method only removes the forms authentication cookie. The Web server does not store valid and expired authentication tickets for later comparison. This makes your site vulnerable to a replay attack if a malicious user obtains a valid forms authentication cookie